# How to loop through a set in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

How do i loop through a set jsp to get content to display? 
heres what i have:

```
public Set<Entry<String, Lesson>> getItems() {
    return chosenLessons.entrySet();
 }
```

servlet code:

```
         if (action.equals("/lessonTimetable")) {
        if (request.getParameter("btnSelect") != null) {
            this.selectedLesson = new LessonSelection(10);
            lessons.ID = request.getParameter("lessonID");
            lessons.description = request.getParameter("lessonDescription");
            lessons.date = request.getParameter("lessonStartDate");
            lessons.startTime = request.getParameter("lessonStartTime");
            lessons.endTime = request.getParameter("lessonEndTime");
            lessons.level = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("lessonLevel"));
            this.selectedLesson.addLesson(lessons);
            session.setAttribute("Username", selectedLesson.getItems());
            System.out.println(selectedLesson.getItems());

   <jsp:useBean id="ChosenLessons" scope="page" class="model.LessonSelection"/>
   <c:forEach var="getAll" items="${ChosenLessons.items}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <c:out value="${getAll}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
```

any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: While running above code, are you facing any error ?

Comment: no error just not what i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in c:forEach... tag use the Set's .toArray() method.

or instead of returning a Set in the getter, you can return the Set's array

```
return chosenLessons.entrySet().toArray();
```

Comment: this can work but i need to avoid having duplicate elements and a set enables me to do that

Comment: you just get an array container with Sets elements :), so in the array will not be any duplicates...

Comment: if you use that method somewhere else you can create a new one with the same behavior but different name :)

Comment: ok that worked but it only displayed one element when i have added two the set, it basically displayed the recently selected item